# Some Cloudfront Distributions are not appearing on AWS Cloudfront Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I can see this Cloudfront distribution (d1ee8khuaj1n9e.cloudfront.net) in Route 53 (see 2nd screenshot -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/C81eF.png). But it seems I can't see it on the Cloudfront Console. My account is now "Global" (see 1st screenshot -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ksPl.png)

Is there lacking with my access or am I looking at the wrong place? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could be different account?

Comment: hi @Marcin, if different account, then why I can see it on Route53? And also, I can't see in the Cloudfront console the serverless one that I created too.

Comment: The record in R53 is a cname or alias record?

Comment: @Marcin an A record

Comment: Can you double check with using AWS CLI `aws cloudfront list-distributions --region us-east-1`?

Comment: In Your distribution, fill out the "Alternate Domain Names" field with your domain name and try again after your distribution is redeployed.

Answer (score 4):

You can check on API Gateway

API Gateway -> Custom Domain Name

The reason is API Gateway's custom domain name feature, when enabled, creates a Cloudfront distribution behind the scene and a Route 53 record pointing to it.

This distribution by API Gateway service is not visible in Cloudfront console.

Comment: How does one find the CloudFront distribution ARN from the API Gateway -> Custom Domain Name page? I'm seeing the DNS records and the "Hosted Zone ID" but these do not appear to be the same as the ARN